# Given a convex function $f(x)$, is $xf'(x)$ also convex?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

Given a convex function $f(x)$, I'm trying to proof that $g(x) = xf'(x)$ is also convex. I have found neither a proof nor a counterexample so far.

A function $g(x)$ is convex iff $g''(x) \ge 0$. Hence, $g''(x) = 2f''(x) + xf'''(x)$ must be nonnegative. Since $f''(x) \ge 0$ by assumption, it remains to show that $xf'''(x) \ge 0$. However, I'm not aware of any statements on the third derivatives of convex functions.

Comment: Are you sure that $f\in \mathcal C^3(\mathbb R)$ (or even in $\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)$) ?

Comment: Let's assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable as many times as necessary (if this helps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be any function such that $$f''(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^4}$$ which is everywhere positive excepted at $x=0$ where it is undefined. Then $xf'''(x)=-\dfrac{4}{x^4}$.

Then we have that $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2} [xf'(x)]$ is negative, since $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2} [xf'(x)] = 2f''(x)+xf'''(x)=-\frac{2}{x^4}$$ which is negative everywhere excepted at $x=0$ where it is undefined.

Note: $f$ has the form $\frac{1}{6x^2}+c_1x+c_2$ for certain constants $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbb R$.